# foreign keys mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table in which I need to submit data. It is a directory listing website on the first table has the common data name etc but I have to manage business hours as well look below

```
 **Users**

Users_Id   Name   Age    AddressId   .........
----+------+------+-----------

**users_hours**

hours_id Users_Id   day   day   day   .........
    ----+------+------+-----------
```

I have to make a foreign key for this but the only issue is how will I get the id of the user dynamically? 
As both of these rows will be created together.

Comment: You can use `mysql_insert_id ()` which will give you the last insertion id. Make a first query to insert into `Users` then use `mysql_insert_id ()`.

Comment: thanks man that did the work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get the last insert `id` of `Users` table, for getting the last `id` you need to use the `mysql_insert_id()` here.

First make a insert query for `Users` and use `$userId = mysql_insert_id()`.

The `$userId` now hold the last id of the `Users` table, so you can now make a second query for `users_hours`.

More about [mysql-insert-id.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)